How can I resolve the issue where Django migrations are not applying changes to the database?
I have a Django app and I'm using PostgreSQL for the database. I've added some new properties to my models, and after making these changes, I ran the following commands:
 python manage.py migrate
 python manage.py makemigrations

A new migration file, 0001_initial.py, was generated with the new properties, such as "hdd_list_remark". However, when I check the database, it seems the migrations are not applied.
One of the models with the added properties is:
    default=HabitatDirectiveChoices.EMPTY, verbose_name=" Habitatrichtlijnen")
    description = models.TextField(
        max_length=5000, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Beschrijving")
    feeding = models.TextField(
        max_length=2000, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Voeding")
    housing = models.TextField(
        max_length=2000, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Huisvesting")
    care = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True,
                            null=True, verbose_name="Verzorging")
    literature = models.TextField(
        max_length=10000, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Literatuur")
    images = models.ImageField(
        upload_to="media/photos/animals", blank=False, null=False, verbose_name="Foto")
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category, related_name='animals', on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Familie")
    date_create = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Datum aangemaakt")
    date_update = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now=True, verbose_name="Datum aangepast")
    animal_images = models.ManyToManyField(
        AnimalImage, related_name='related_animals', blank=True)
    files = models.ManyToManyField(
        AnimalFile, related_name='related_animals_files', blank=True)

The migration file: 0001_initial.py looks:
# Generated by Django 5.0.6 on 2024-08-28 12:36

import django.db.models.deletion
from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = []

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name="Animal",
            fields=[
                (
                    "id",
                    models.BigAutoField(
                        auto_created=True,
                        primary_key=True,
                        serialize=False,
                        verbose_name="ID",
                    ),
                ),
                (
                    "hdd_list_remark",
                    models.TextField(
                        blank=True, max_length=500, verbose_name="HDD lijst opmerking"
                    ),
                ),
                ("name", models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="Naam")),
                (
                    "sort",
                    models.CharField(
                        default="", max_length=100, verbose_name="Soort(Latijn)"
                    ),
                ),
                ("slug", models.SlugField(editable=False, max_length=100)),
                (
                    "cites",
                    models.CharField(
                        choices=[
                            ("", ""),
                            ("A", "A"),
                            ("B", "B"),
                            ("A/B", "A/B"),
                            ("C", "C"),
                            ("D", "D"),
                            ("nvt", "nvt"),
                        ],
                        default="",
                        max_length=5,
                        verbose_name="Cites",
                    ),
                ),
                ("uis", models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="UIS")),
                (
                    "pet_list",
                    models.CharField(
                        choices=[
                            ("", ""),
                            ("ja", "ja"),
                            ("nee", "nee"),
                            ("nvt", "nvt"),
                        ],
                        default="",
                        max_length=3,
                        verbose_name=" HDD lijst",
                    ),
                ),
                (
                    "bird_directive_list",
                    models.CharField(
                        blank=True,
                        choices=[
                            ("", ""),
                            ("TrekVogel", "TrekVogel"),
                            ("Bijlage|", "Bijlage |"),
                            ("Bijlage ||/1", "Bijlage ||/2"),
                            ("Bijlage ||/2", "Bijlage ||/2"),
                            ("Bijlage |||/1", "Bijlage |||/1 "),
                            ("Bijlage |||/3", "Bijlage |||/3"),
                            ("nvt", "nvt"),
                        ],
                        default="",
                        max_length=13,
                        verbose_name=" Vogelrichtlijnen",
                    ),
                ),
                (
                    "Habitat_directive_list",
                    models.CharField(
                        blank=True,
                        choices=[
                            ("", ""),
                            ("Bijlage||", "Bijlage ||"),
                            ("Bijlage |V", "Bijlage |V"),
                            ("Bijlage V ", "Bijlage V"),
                            ("nvt", "nvt"),
                        ],
                        default="",
                        max_length=13,
                        verbose_name=" Habitatrichtlijnen",
                    ),
                ),
                (
                    "description",
                    models.TextField(
                        blank=True,
                        max_length=5000,
                        null=True,
                        verbose_name="Beschrijving",
                    ),
                ),
                (
                    "feeding",
                    models.TextField(
                        blank=True, max_length=2000, null=True, verbose_name="Voeding"
                    ),
                ),
                (
                    "housing",
                    models.TextField(
                        blank=True,
                        max_length=2000,
                        null=True,
                        verbose_name="Huisvesting",
                    ),
                ),
                (
                    "care",
                    models.TextField(
                        blank=True,
                        max_length=1000,
                        null=True,
                        verbose_name="Verzorging",
                    ),
                ),
                (
                    "literature",
                    models.TextField(
                        blank=True,
                        max_length=10000,
                        null=True,
                        verbose_name="Literatuur",
                    ),
                ),
                (
                    "images",
                    models.ImageField(
                        upload_to="media/photos/animals", verbose_name="Foto"
                    ),
                ),
                (
                    "date_create",
                    models.DateTimeField(
                        auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Datum aangemaakt"
                    ),
                ),
                (
                    "date_update",
                    models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="Datum aangepast"),
                ),
            ],
            options={
                "verbose_name": "Dier",
                "verbose_name_plural": "Dieren",
                "managed": True,
            },
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name="AnimalFile",
            fields=[
                (
                    "id",
                    models.BigAutoField(
                        auto_created=True,
                        primary_key=True,
                        serialize=False,
                        verbose_name="ID",
                    ),
                ),
                (
                    "file",
                    models.FileField(
                        upload_to="media/files/animals", verbose_name="Bestand"
                    ),
                ),
                (
                    "file_name",
                    models.CharField(
                        blank=True, max_length=255, verbose_name="Bestandsnaam"
                    ),
                ),
                (
                    "animal",
                    models.ForeignKey(
                        on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE,
                        related_name="animal_files",
                        to="DierenWelzijnAdmin.animal",
                    ),
                ),
            ],
            options={
                "verbose_name": "Dierbestand",
                "verbose_name_plural": "Dierbestanden",
                "managed": True,
            },
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name="animal",
            name="files",
            field=models.ManyToManyField(
                blank=True,
                related_name="related_animals_files",
                to="DierenWelzijnAdmin.animalfile",
            ),
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name="AnimalImage",
            fields=[
                (
                    "id",
                    models.BigAutoField(
                        auto_created=True,
                        primary_key=True,
                        serialize=False,
                        verbose_name="ID",
                    ),
                ),
                ("image", models.ImageField(upload_to="media/photos/animals")),
                (
                    "animal",
                    models.ForeignKey(
                        on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE,
                        related_name="imag",
                        to="DierenWelzijnAdmin.animal",
                    ),
                ),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name="animal",
            name="animal_images",
            field=models.ManyToManyField(
                blank=True,
                related_name="related_animals",
                to="DierenWelzijnAdmin.animalimage",
            ),
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name="Category",
            fields=[
                (
                    "id",
                    models.BigAutoField(
                        auto_created=True,
                        primary_key=True,
                        serialize=False,
                        verbose_name="ID",
                    ),
                ),
                (
                    "name",
                    models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, verbose_name="Naam"),
                ),
                (
                    "description",
                    models.TextField(
                        blank=True,
                        max_length=5000,
                        null=True,
                        verbose_name="Beschrijving",
                    ),
                ),
                (
                    "images",
                    models.ImageField(
                        upload_to="media/photos/categories", verbose_name="Foto"
                    ),
                ),
                (
                    "date_create",
                    models.DateTimeField(
                        auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Datum aangemaakt"
                    ),
                ),
                (
                    "date_update",
                    models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="Datum geupdate"),
                ),
                (
                    "category",
                    models.ForeignKey(
                        blank=True,
                        null=True,
                        on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE,
                        related_name="subcategories",
                        to="DierenWelzijnAdmin.category",
                        verbose_name="Categorie",
                    ),
                ),
            ],
            options={
                "verbose_name": "Categorie",
                "verbose_name_plural": "Categoriën",
                "managed": True,
            },
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name="animal",
            name="category",
            field=models.ForeignKey(
                on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE,
                related_name="animals",
                to="DierenWelzijnAdmin.category",
                verbose_name="Familie",
            ),
        ),
    ]


I've tried several troubleshooting steps, including:

Creating a backup of the database.
Deleting and recreating the database, then restoring it.
Deleting all migration files except 0001_initial.py, and running the
migrations again.
Refreshing the database in PostgreSQL.

Despite these efforts, the migrations still don't seem to apply.
this are all the messages C:\repos\DWL_backend_Rachid> python manage.py makemigrations
System check identified some issues:



Question: How can I ensure that the migrations are properly applied to the database?

You need to run these in the opposite order: first makemigrations then migrate.

It makes perfect sense that the migrations are not applied. migrate applies the migrations created, for example by makemigrations, so you need to first run makemigrations and then migrate:
python manage.py makemigrations  # first
python manage.py migrate         # second

If you first migrate, there are no migration files to run on the database, and next you make these migration files, but they are not applied.

@mightycodeNewton: so there are migration files when you do that?

@mightycodeNewton: so what is the name of the app?

@mightcodeNewton: but you removed the "old" migration file? Well in that case a makemigration will have created a new one (again 0001), but it will not migrate it, since django_migrations already contains an 0001, so the database "thinks" it has migratied.  This is the reason why you should not remove migration files.

@mightycodeNewton: if you have the old file, for example in subversioning. Retrieve the old file, set that as 0001 again, run makemigrations such that Django creates an 0002 and migrate the database.

If you can not somehow retrieve the old 0001 that has been migrated in the database, destroy the database, and repeat 100'000 times "I must not remove migration files".

@mightycodeNewton: not (only) restoring the database. The idea is that the database has a table, django_migrations that lists what migrations it has done, so here dierenwelzijnadmin,0001 will be listed. So the database assumes it has migrated 0001. If you later change 0001, then trouble arrives.

That is why you should not tamper with migration files already done. It means that makemigration will no longer see changes because 0001 will be in sync with the models.py, and the database will not see any changes to perform, since it has done the bookkeeping. You thus should look to recover the 0001_....py file content at the moment you made the initial migration of that file.

I already solved this issue. But I can not delete the post.
